# Installing software from user account as admin without having to log off log in

Tags: windows-7, installation, group-policy, privileges, popups

Is there a way with a GPO to allow an administrator to install a software from a standard user account?

Let say I want to install Itunes from a standard account. I would like Windows 7 to pop an authentication windows asking for admin privileges. Right now, I must log off and log in as admin to install a software.

Comment: Yes?  Use [`run as administrator or runas from a command prompt`](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html) from a command prompt.

Comment: By default it should pop up and ask you for admin credentials.  Sounds like you may have applied a GPO to stop that (on purpose)?